# "Manufactured in a facility that processes peanuts, tree nuts and dairy/milk products" on food label

Tags: alimentation

How would I properly translate the phrase: "Manufactured in a facility that processes peanuts, tree nuts and dairy/milk products" to French, as would be included in a food label? I live in Canada, so any links to examples where your translated phrase is used on products would be most helpful.

For example here's one as used to meet FDA (USA) standards: http://www.foodlabels.com/q&a.htm#Allergy_Statement

Also, how would I specifically state: "*Brewed* in a facility that processes peanuts, tree nuts and dairy/milk products"?

---

edit:

Would an adequate choice for "brewed" (as in tea) be:

> infusé

to render (using a mix of both answers provided so far):

> Infusé dans un établissement qui utilise d'arachides, de noix ou de produits laitiers.

?

Comment: A different way to translate is: Peut avoir été en contact avec des arachides, des noix et/ou des produits laitiers.

Comment: Thanks @Archa, how would I translate the original phrase though?

Comment: About your edit: yes, "_infusé_" is the translation of "brewed" for tea. Use the masculine form, however, since you do not specify the subject and masculine is the default in French ("_thé_" is masculine in French anyway).

Comment: @Chop, thanks, fixed. Goes to show how poor my grasp of French is that I didn't even know that was the feminine form. So does that full sentence properly convey what I am trying to say?

Comment: @RaphaelRosch I'll write an answer to sum up all that's been said, as comments are not to be used like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go piece by piece here.

#### Manufactured/Brewed

- Manufactured: since we are talking of food, I guess the best word would be "*Préparé*".
- Brewed: in your specific context, you are talking about tea, so we agreed on "*infusé*".

#### Facility

This is a hard one since it is quite vague. "*Atelier*" is commonly used. It does render as "shop", but hardly the selling kind. Rather a place where (manual) craft is performed (sewing shop, workshop, repair shop, ...). The *atelier* can be the place where the selling takes place but it is often in a separate room or building.

If you want to keep really neutral, "*bâtiment*" is the literal translation for "building".

#### Process

Literally, this is the verb "*traiter*". "*Utiliser*" is however more common for this context.

#### Peanuts, tree nuts and dairy/milk products

- Peanuts: "*cachuètes*" or, more widely, "*arachides*".
- Tree nuts: there is no French term for all tree nuts. "*Noix*" is for "walnuts" only.

You could use "[*fruits à coque*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_%C3%A0_coque)" ("shelled fruit") as [Alexandre d'Entraigues suggested](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14269/7224). It regroups both peanuts and tree nuts.

- Dairy: "*produits laitiers*".

## Bringing it all together

Keeping close to standards is a good idea as it allows consumers to easily understand the sentence since they are used to see it everywhere when they are looking for allergens.

As a consequence, I would go with the following (which is close to [what Alexandre d'Entraigues proposed](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14269/7224)):

> Préparé/Infusé dans un atelier qui utilise des fruits à coque et des produits laitiers.

This is implied in [cl-r's proposition](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14259/7224):

> Peut contenir des traces de fruits à coque ou de produits laitiers.

---

<sub>**Minor note:**</sub>

<sub>In the first form, we used "*des*", not in the second form. The additional products are countable, so we use a definite article, which contracts with "*de*" ("*de + les = des*"). In the second form, since there are only traces, they become uncountable and we use only "*de*", without the article.</sub>

Comment: I also read yesterday that "noix" in French literally means "walnut" and is not to be used as the generic term for "nut". (I read this while researching Alexandre d'Entraigues's answer's usage of "fruits à coque").

Comment: @RaphaelRosch You are correct. I adapted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Très souvent traduit en :

> Peut contenir des traces d'arachides, de noix ou de produits laitiers.

*Traces* indique que des quantités infimes peuvent avoir été laissées par les produits qui ont été traités précédemment malgré le nettoyage des machines, ou que les composants originaux, qu'ils soient solides ou liquides, peuvent eux-mêmes en contenir.

---

***EDIT***

Plutôt que *Infusé* (qui pourrait être très bien compris) l'usage est, pour les liquides :

> ***Mis en bouteille*** dans une chaîne ayant pu traiter des arachides, des noix ou des produits laitiers.

N.B. : la *mise en bouteille* signifie l'*embouteillage* ou le *flaconnage*, mais l'usage et la traçabilité veulent que ce soit le dernier intervenant sur le produit qui est responsable de ce dernier : il doit vérifier et tracer tous les composants du produit qu'il livre aux consommateurs.

On peut remplacer *une chaîne* par *un établissement, un atelier* selon le lieu de fabrication.

Comment: Tu peux préciser que ta proposition s'applique aussi bien à « _manufactured_ » que « _brewed_ ».

Comment: @Chop Quelle est votre traduction de  « brewed » ?

Comment: @clr Je bois peut-être trop de bière, mais le premier mot qui me vient à l'esprit est « brassé ». Plus généralement, cela va s'appliquer à la [préparation d'un comestible _liquide_](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/brew), tandis que _manufactured_ s'applique à [la préparation/fabrication de solide (comestible ou non)](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/manufacture).

Comment: @Chop J'avais la même idée, mais je me demandais s'il n'y avait pas un piège ; j'ai complété ma réponse.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I want to avoid mentioning "traces" or "may contain", I want to be as brief as possible and as faithful to the English phrase above as well. Also, as you might surmise, my French is not strong enough that I can precisely understand everything you guys are writing, though I do appreciate the exercise.

Comment: @RaphaelRosch Sorry. We just said that this proposition could apply to "manufactured" as well as "brewed".

Comment: @RaphaelRosch L'intérêt du site est de montrer que les traductions mots à mots sont inélégantes et parfois incompréhensibles, surtout quand c'est un chinois qui traduit une notice de l'anglais en français... et cela se voit tout de suite. C'est une des clefs de la 'French touch' de n'être pas aussi condensable que l'anglais, cela devrait la rendre plus glamour.

Comment: @cl-r, yeah, I certainly get that, the problem is that I am fluent in Spanish, another Romance language, and a lot of these expressions do sound natural in it when it comes to food labelling, for example. This is where my doubt arises, I "feel" like it should be possible, you know?

Answer (score 2):

You'll also sometimes find

> Fabriqué dans un atelier qui utilise des fruits à coque
>
> Fabriqué dans un atelier utilisant des fruits à coque

which is a closer translation but means the same thing as « Peut contenir des traces de fruits à coques ».

Comment: I looked up "atelier" but it renders it as "shop". Would "établissement" be an adequate choice instead?

Comment: @RaphaelRosch You could use "_bâtiment_" (literally: "building"). "_Atelier_" is fine, though. The primary meaning is a place where (manual) crafting is done. Sometimes, you just happen to sell there too. The translations Alexandre proposes are standards. I have seen them on several products.

Comment: @Chop, awesome. With that hint, I found: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/fabriqu%C3%A9+dans+un+atelier+qui+utilise.html which confirms it for me.

Comment: "fruits à coque" just learned a new word (I guess "term" would be more precise).